# How to prevent `xxxx.xxx ms script spike detected in behavior pack` message?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

I have a behavior pack that uses a script module. In the script file, I am using `world.events.beforeItemUse.subscribe` to track custom item usage. However, the first item use each time the world loads is delayed by up to 1300 milliseconds before activating, and this triggers a variation on the following message in the content log.

```
12:43:55[Scripting][warning]-[Watchdog] 1293.468 ms script spike detected in behavior pack '<behavior pack name>'
```

**How do I either fix this delay, or stop only this specific watchdog error from logging?**